# VSCode: How to fix red highlight in vscode jupyter

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting following red highlight while I write the code inside the jupyter cell. The color theme used is "Bluloco Light Italic"

[image]

This is how I get the highlight while using the color theme "Dark + (default dark)"

[image]

I tried the VSCode Bisect, but didnt work. Kindly help in removing the highlight. Thanks.

Comment: That indicates an error. What error is it?

Comment: I am getting the following error message: `Expected expression to the right of "="`

Comment: In your first example, you get that error because you don't have anything after the `=`, it just ends and so you get all the red. In your second example, it's invalid (and so all the red) since the `for` line needs to end with a colon and needs to have a body starting on the next line. (`pass` is sufficient for that.)

Comment: @Ouroborus but I dont get this error while using the vscode text editor, i get this only in vscode jupyter editor.

Comment: Hover with your mouse over the `def` part. What does it say? Please read everything carefully and paste here

Comment: Or do you just want to get rid of the background highlighting for errors in general ( like dark+ does for example)?

Comment: @uloco I would like to get rid of the background highlighting error only in Jupyter notebook. And when i hover my mouse over the `def` part, it dows not say or show anything.

Comment: When I type the same thing in a notebook, I don't get everything highlighted. Just the part where the = error is happening. after fixing this it looks clean. It has to do with some local setup of yours.. Probably something with your jupyter setup is broken?